# Convert struct fields from string to number

Tags: matlab

I have a struct with several fields, some that should be numeric, and some that should be char. However, after my use of `regexp` I have chars in the fields that I want to use as numbers.

For example:

```
foo.str = 'one';
foo.data = '1';
foo(2).str = 'two';
foo(2).data = '2';
```

In my dreams I could do: `foo.data = str2double(foo.data)`, but this does not work.

I could iterate through the struct, but that's only an ok option.
It's a long struct (100,000) with about 20 files.

```
for i = 1:length(foo)
    foo(i).data = str2double(foo(i).data);
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect all elements from the subfield and call str2double once:

```
str2double({foo.data})
```

Comment: This is a partial answer. It is incomplete because the data has changed shape from a struct of size>1 to an array, and I don't know how to get it back.

Comment: @Frederick It wasn't clear that you want to keep it in the struct. Why? Struct are inefficient and memory and speedwise.

Comment: It *is* super slow. (~500seconds). I like the organization of the struct rather than having to keep track of 20 variables. The ability to do `struct.('some_field_name')` is what helps. I can do something like that using discrete variables, but I have to use `eval` statements, which make the code hard to read.

Comment: I went with this and now how a length==1 struct with long arrays for each field. I can still use the `struct.('some_field_name')` syntax.

Comment: @Frederick Sorry I could not follow up, but you can look up datasets. I prefer them by far to structs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly compact solution that `deal`s numerical values back into each `foo.data`:

```
fdnc = num2cell(str2double({foo.data}));
[foo.data] = deal(fdnc{:});
```

Remember to clear and redefine `foo` when testing.

**EDIT**: Fixed `vertcat` problem with multiple digits. Thanks, nispio.

Comment: `vertcat(foo.data)` will fail unless all of the `data` elements have the same number of digits.

Comment: @nispio - Thanks for the tip.  fixed.  Now it should provide the solution with any number of digits, I think.

Comment: +1 This is surprisingly compact *and* readable. Those don't always go hand-in-hand.

Comment: A good option. I wonder which of the options presented is the fastest.

Comment: @Frederick - This is the fastest way to update your cell, but Oleg's doesn't do that at all, so it will of course be faster.

Answer (score 1):

A little cumbersome, but this works; no loops:

```
N = length(foo);
[aux_str{1:N}] = deal(foo.str);
[aux_data{1:N}] = deal(foo.data);
aux_data = mat2cell(str2double(aux_data),1,ones(1,N));
foo = cell2struct([aux_str; aux_data],{'str','data'},1);
```